# Prevent scroll bar to go up when click mobile nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, nav

I have a mobile nav and I open it using this code in JS file:

```js
var toggleButton = document.querySelector(".toggle-button");
var mobileNav = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  mobileNav.classList.add("slide");
});

closeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  mobileNav.classList.remove("slide");
});
```

```css
.mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  transform: translateX(1400px);
}

.slide {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

when I scroll down and open mobile nav using slide class the scroll bar goes up, how to fix it? i want it to remain at current place where I open slide menu.

here is project Github page for more codes:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/Vahidpro/portfolio-service)

and here is the online website for reprodure the issue, just make browser page smaller than 768px and scroll down then tap hamburger icon to see the issue.

[enter link description here](https://cvservice.netlify.ap)

Comment: can you add the minimum html to display the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const navSection = document.querySelector(".nav-section");

function openNav() {
  navSection.classList.add("open-nav")
}

function closeNav() {
  navSection.classList.remove("open-nav")
}
```

```css
.nav-section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-section nav{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 20rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.open-nav{
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.open-nav nav{
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.close-nav-btn{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="open-btn">
  <button onclick="openNav()">open</button>
</div>

<section class="nav-section">
  <nav>
    <a>nav 0</a>
    <a>nav 1</a>
    <a>nav 2</a>
    <a>nav 3</a>
  </nav>
  <button onclick="closeNav()" class="close-nav-btn">close</button>
</section>
```

Like this maybe?